# Как плавно перемещать линию SVG по прямоугольному пути?

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

Я пытаюсь воссоздать следующую анимацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня проблемы с правильной анимацией линии вокруг углов.
Я пробовал использовать такой элемент анимации - `animateMotion:`

```
<line class="testLine" x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="10" stroke="white"> 
        <animateMotion dur="1.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" 
            path="M 10 10 L 390 10
             M 390 10 L 390 290
             M 390 290 L 10 290
             M 10 290 L 10 10"> 
        </animateMotion>
</line>
```

Но линия не плавно закругляет углы.

Есть идеи, как заставить её плавно перемещаться по углам, как показано в GIF выше?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Smoothly move an SVG line along a rectangular path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64015656/7394871) от участника  [@HaakonFlaar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9880480/haakonflaar).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64015656/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Та же штуковина, только за счет скейла и ротейта, ну и поменьше кода

```js
document.querySelector('svg').innerHTML = [...Array(11)]
  .map((_, i) => Math.pow(2, i/2))
  .map((s, i) => `
    <path transform="scale(${s})rotate(${i*45})" 
          stroke-width="${2/s}" 
          d="m5,5h-10v-10h10z"></path>
`).join(',');
```

```css
path {
  stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  animation: shift 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes shift {
  100% {stroke-dashoffset: -20}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='-200,-200,400,400' width="90vw" height="90vh"></svg>
```

Comment: отличное решение, хороший ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно будет создать путь с srtoke-dasharray = 1/2 стороны прямоугольника и анимировать смещение stroke-dashoffset пути до `0`
Пожалуйста, прочтите комментарии в коде:

```js
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let sz = 50;//initial size 1/2 rect side
//the array of the paths. Inside the array uou have a first object for the path #p
let sqRy = [{ s: sz, d: "", l: p.getTotalLength(), el: p }];

//create several paths and rotate those paths accordingly
for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
  let o = {};
  let size = sqRy[i - 1].s / 2;
  
  o.s = Math.sqrt(2 * size * size);
  //значение атрибута d нового пути
  o.d = `M-${o.s},-${o.s}L${o.s},-${o.s} ${o.s},${o.s} -${o.s},${o.s} -${o.s},-${o.s}z`;

  o.el = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, "path");
  o.el.setAttribute("d", o.d);//установить атрибут d
  o.el.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${45 * i})`);//установить велечину угла вращения
  svg.appendChild(o.el);//добавить новый патч
  o.l = o.el.getTotalLength();//рассчитать общую длину нового пути
  //push объект для пути к массиву
  sqRy.push(o);
}


//для каждого элемента в массиве установите stroke-dasharray и stroke-dashoffset.
sqRy.map((sq) => {
  sq.el.setAttribute("style", `stroke-dasharray:${sq.s};stroke-dashoffset:${sq.l}`);
});
```

```css
svg{fill:none;stroke:black;}

path{
     animation: dash 16s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" viewBox="-60 -60 120 120" id="svg">
  <path id="p" d="M-50,-50L50,-50 50,50 -50,50 -50,-50z" />  
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029071/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>